# What are email addresses at the domain devnull.spamcop.net used for in SpamCop?

Tags: spamcop

I see a few different addresses in my [SpamCop *inprogress* display](http://www.spamcop.net/w3m?action=inprogress):

```
nomaster@devnull.spamcop.net
abuse#anti-spam.cn@devnull.spamcop.net
abuse#strato.de@devnull.spamcop.net
sidhom#ati.tn@devnull.spamcop.net
```

What do these mean:

that there was no abuse e-mail for these domains or,
that the account didn't respond or,
that the account was not accepting e-mail?

Any information on the email domain `devnull.spamcop.net` would probably satisfy my curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently these address are either for statistical tracking within the SpamCop system:

> Using abuse#anti-spam.cn@devnull.spamcop.net for statistical tracking.

Or in the case of **nomaster@devnull.spamcop.net**

> No reporting addresses found for 130.255.251.212, using devnull for tracking.
>
> No valid email addresses found, sorry!